# SQL Server Stored Procedure -Non-numeric values caused by text fields being parsed out

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How can I parse out non-numeric values using a stored procedure? I have a table that I replicate in an SSIS package. Unfortunately, when this table sends to the gpg output it includes values like:, |, \, .

Example - this is what the result set looks like for my `Title` column:

```
FLASH| BANG| POP| FIZZ|: E-OP 
YES, YOU CAN|||: POSITIVE -OP
```

and I need it to be:

```
FLASH BANG POP FIZZ
YES, YOU CAN POSITIVE -OP
```

Is there a way to remove these unwanted values using a stored procedure?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes you can do that. You need to define what characters you don't want in the final data though. It looks like you want to remove | and :. But why is E-OP removed from the first one? Once you have the rules defined this is pretty simple.

Comment: E-OP should have stayed that was a goof on my behalf.

Comment: So a simple nested replace would solve this. Replace(replace(YourColumn, '|', ''), ':', ''). Or do it directly in your SSIS package.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `UPDATE` in a stored procedure using the `REPLACE` function but why not cleanse them in your SSIS using a Derived Column operator in your data flow?

Comment: I've never used a Derived Column operator before. I'll check into that. Thanks :)